# Program working fine for smaller values but throwing Segmentation Fault for bigger values

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In the following program when the value of N is less than 100 the program is executing perfectly but for bigger values of N its showing segmentation fault.I sit because of less memory or anything wrong with program??

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()

{
int N,iteration,MAX_ITERATONS;

int i,j,k,n,index,boundary1,boundary2;

double h[2][100][100];

int current = 0;

int next = 1;

printf("Enter the number of points\n ");

scanf("%d", &N);

boundary1=0.4*N;

boundary2=(0.6*N);

printf("The boundary is between %d and %d    .\n",boundary1,boundary2);

for(k=0;k<2;k++)

{

for(i=0;i<N;i++)

{

    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {

            if((i==0)&&(j>=boundary1&&j<boundary2))
            h[k][i][j]=100;
            else
            h[k][i][j]=20;

        }

}

}

printf("Initial Values\n");

index = N/10;

for(i=0;i<N;)

{   

for(j=0;j<N;)

    {   

    printf("%.2f\t",h[0][i][j]);

        j=j+index;

    }

    i=i+index;

    printf("\n");

 }


}
```

Comment: `double h[2][100][100]`. What do you think will happen when `N` is greater than 100 and you use that as the upper limit of your `h` array indexes?

Comment: Thank you very much..such a silly mistake..

Comment: Why do you have a blank line between every line of your program ??

Comment: I edited it for posting it here..it was not showing proper indentation..Just started using stack overflow..

Comment: BTW your indentation is not proper at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When N > 100, `h` is accessed to an index greater than 100, inside the nested for loop

```
h[k][i][j]=100;
```

but `h` is defined as

```
double h[2][100][100];
```

You are going out of bounds for `h`

If you want `N` as greater than 100 you need to redefine `h` or malloc it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out...